# Background image not scaling correctly on mobile

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have this background image. Its working fine and fills up the entire screen vertically on desktop and tablet correctly. When it gets to mobile however it starts to scaled down a bit and shoe these nasty white bars.

[image]

Here is the css:

```
html {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("../../assets/imgs/MenuBackground1.png");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;


}
```

Comment: Did you try adding a media query for mobile screens and changing the background-size property? Try background-size: contain for mobile screens.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing background-size to 100%